# PHP Object tree to Nested Complex Header Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, pivot-table, laravel-blade

I am trying to convert the array tree to pivot table headers Right Now I have array like this. From this array table headers will be generated dynamically. I have hierarchy through which I want to create dynamic headers of tables:

```
      array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#643 ▼
      +"id": 6
      +"title": "Col 1"
      +"parent": null
      +"created_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
      +"updated_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
      +"children": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#639 ▼
          +"id": 10
          +"title": "Mh Col"
          +"parent": "6"
          +"created_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
          +"updated_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#640 ▼
      +"id": 7
      +"title": "Col 2"
      +"parent": null
      +"created_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
      +"updated_at": "2020-04-27 17:01:08"
      +"children": []
    }
  ]
]
```

How I am trying to print the table:

```
            @foreach ($tbHeaders  as $tb)
              <tr>
              <th rowspan="2">{{ $tb->title }}</th>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
```

I am looking for this type of header:

[image: Pivot Table Image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your feedback. question is just to convert the hierarchic tree to  dynamic complex headers.

Comment: That's not a question. As said, Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kerbholz  Thanks again. I updated my question. I try to minimize the code as much as I can. pasted only to the point code.